# Is my linux machine Ubuntu and what is the meaning of that?

Tags: mint

eli5: Is my Linux Mint machine Ubuntu? and what is the difference between ubuntu and say debian? and what other Linux OS's are there out there??

I just say the word Ubuntu and pretend to sound smart in front of my friends muahah!!

Comment: You may find this [unix.se] question helpful: [Classification of Linux distributions](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/14378/classification-of-linux-distributions)

Answer (score 7):

1. [Linux Mint](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_Mint) is based on [Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/about/about-ubuntu/ubuntu-and-debian) which in turn is based on Debian. So there you go! From the Ubuntu website:

> Debian can be considered the rock upon which Ubuntu is built. It is a
>   volunteer project that has developed and maintained a GNU/Linux
>   operating system of the same name for well over a decade....

and:

> Ubuntu is an open source project that develops and maintains a
>   cross-platform, open-source operating system based on Debian. It
>   includes Unity, a consistent user interface for the smartphone, the
>   tablet and the PC....

2. You are using Linux Mint and not Ubuntu.
3. There are hundreds of linux distributions out there - have a look at [DistroWatch](http://distrowatch.com/dwres.php?resource=major) or [this](http://www.linux.com/directory/Software/new) list. This [image](http://futurist.se/gldt/wp-content/uploads/10.11/gldt1011.svg) shows you the connections between several distributions (pretty cool!)